# NestJS enable cors in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cors, nestjs

I've enabled CORS in my NestJS app following [the official tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cors), so my `main.ts` looks like the following:

```
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter(), { cors: true });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and it works when I run the application using `npm run start:dev`.

However when I try to first compile the application using `npm run webpack` and then running it using `node server.js`, the cors will not work.

The http request from the client will fail with:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: check if you have some extension in the browser blocking 3rd javascript, e.g. NoScript and Privacy Badger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somehow the issue was compiling it using `npm run webpack`. If I compile it using `prestart:prod` then it will work.

Thanks @georgii-rychko for suggesting it via comments.

Answer (score 86):

Try to use an approach described in here https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#cors

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.enableCors();
await app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Also, I have a question: why do you build your server app using webpack? Usually, just simple `tsc` call is used.

Comment: Thank you but I've already tried this solution and unfortunately it does not work. I compile for production using `npm run webpack` which I guess it's the default way to do it with NestJS, isn't it?

Comment: ShinDarth, have a look at this official example. There you can find how the app gets built https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/10-fastify.

Comment: Try to build your app using this example as a basis.

Comment: Here is the compilation command from the `scripts` section of the package.json:

```"prestart:prod": "tsc"```. Just try to play with this example. In case you'll have questions - just put them here.

Comment: `app.enableCors()` uses default configs which seem to be invalid for some browsers (at least Chrome complains that wildcard is not allowed). Correct way would be to use `app.enableCors({ origin: /.+/ });`

Answer (score 67):

If you are running NestJs with graphql you will run into a problem where Apollo server will override the CORS setting [see link](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/134#issuecomment-413543241). This below fixed the problem. I wasted 8 hrs of my life on this. :-( I hope you see this and you don't do that. see [link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1142#issuecomment-486657060) and [link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1579)

```
        GraphQLModule.forRoot({
            debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
            playground: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
            typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
            installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
            context: ({req}) => {
                return {req};
            },
            cors: {
                credentials: true,
                origin: true,
            },
        }),
```

then in your main.ts:

```
        app.enableCors({
            origin: true,
            methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
            credentials: true,
        });
```

Answer (score 30):

The documentation for the cors config object is here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options

I noticed nobody used an array for the origin, so in case anyone wanted some quick copy pasta

And in case you were wondering, I researched it too... http and https is considered different and so are subdomains or lack thereof ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and app.example.com).

```js
app.enableCors({
  origin: [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://example.com',
    'http://www.example.com',
    'http://app.example.com',
    'https://example.com',
    'https://www.example.com',
    'https://app.example.com',
  ],
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  credentials: true,
});
```

Answer (score 16):

I was able to get it working by giving my own origin function. The complete enableCors function would be like for NestJS or any NodeJS server like:

```
var whitelist = ['https://website.com', 'https://www.website.com'];
app.enableCors({
origin: function (origin, callback) {
  if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
    console.log("allowed cors for:", origin)
    callback(null, true)
  } else {
    console.log("blocked cors for:", origin)
    callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
  }
},
allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Observe',
methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS",
credentials: true,
});
```

and the appOptions if you are using NestJS Express:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 8):

Sad to know that you also tried:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.enableCors();
await app.listen(3000);
```

And it's still not working.

---

Ensure that on your server side you have [cors](https://enable-cors.org/) enabled, which should be something like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

And also ensure that your browser is [cors](https://enable-cors.org/client.html) supported. If all these still doesn't work, I will advice you download [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) extension for Chrome, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 6):

maybe you get `undefined` in origin with the following whitelist .If you do not want to block **REST tools** or **server-to-server requests**, add a `!origin` check in the origin function like so:

```
const whitelist = ['example.com', 'api.example.com'];
app.enableCors({
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: A bit of more explanation regarding what does "if you do not want to block REST tools or server-to-server request" mean: I was configuring my NestJS app and then I realized that I am getting CORS error when I try to open swagger doc in my browser, so after reading [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63684532/8784518) I understood what was wrong with my app; since I was sending a request to my NestJS app from the same origin, browser was not adding the origin header to the request. So we need to allow those requests to pass our CORS policy enforcer.

Answer (score 3):

Bellow is my main.ts that finally worked pretty well.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
        AppModule,
    );

    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
    app.setBaseViewsDir(join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));
    app.setViewEngine('hbs');

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
        next();
    });

    app.enableCors({
        allowedHeaders:"*",
        origin: "*"
    });

    await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 3):

Who wants to use **CORS policy dynamically** (for example you store origins in the database):

```
app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: async (requestOrigin: string, next: (err: Error | null, origin?: string[]) => void) => {
        const origins = await app.get(AppService).getOrigins();

        // origins: StaticOrigin = ['https://google.com', 'http://localhost'];
        next(null, origins);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using Angular and Nest. So I just enable cors when I create app in main.ts.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

Another option is:

```
 app.enableCors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials: true,
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the other answers, but found the following works for me

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
await app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers had worked until I realized `nest start` would run with no issues when I deleted my `main.ts` file.

Check that your `main.ts` is actually being called.

If it's not, **deleting the /dist folder should do the trick.**

Answer (score 0):

```
async function bootstrap() {
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter());
app.enableCors()
await app.listen(3000); 
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable cors in azure. Just in case somebody has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to ensure that the response will come with the correct header.
Exemple, if you want to release all origins then the header should look like this:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[image]

And for this, use:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
app.enableCors();
```

you need to check these details before coding.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const PORT = 5000;
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000"});

  await app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started`));
}

bootstrap();
```

Instead of "http://localhost:3000" paste your url client

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score -3):

run on production mode

```
npm run start:prod
```