# Enable Cors in NestJs

Tags: cors, nestjs

I want to use a NestJs api, but I get the same error message in each `fetch`:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/articles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My frontend is an Angular, where I have a simple `fetch` :

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/articles')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

I tried these options in my NestJs - but none of them seem to work:

**Attempt A**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept',
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Attempt B**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Attempt C**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: nestjs uses the cors module from expressjs/cors https://github.com/expressjs/cors  . The `origin: true` property is used per route to enable cors for that specific route. As this is a general change I think I would try to change that to `origin: '*'` to see if it works. Ultimately it should be the domain from where the request is being initiated

Comment: @VladNeacsu same was ``'*'`` or ``'localhost'`` or ``'localhost:4200'``

Comment: There must be a non related issue because the second example from your code with `app.enableCors();` seems to work fine. Have you tried restart the application after the change? Also, the port doesn't matter and from the error you're not making a cross domain request

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJS enable cors in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949231/nestjs-enable-cors-in-production)

Answer (score 8):

On your `main.ts`, edit bootstrap function as follows to enable `CORS`

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

Or

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.enableCors();
```

This method helps you to pass additional params for cors

Read more about [CORS here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/security#cors)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `cors` npm module. Install cors by running the command
`npm install cors --save`

After installation, in your main.ts file paste the below line.

```js
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: this is work on my nestjs + serverless + aws

Answer (score 2):

`main.ts`

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
});
await app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to CORS headers is to standup a webserver such as Nginix on your computer and proxy all your requests through it, forwarding to the appropriate port based on a url root.  This is how things are normally approached in the real world as the CORS headers are relatively new and can open security holes you may not want by default.

This solves the fundamental problem that is your application is running on a different Origin (protocol + domain + port) than the api you want to access.