# CORS is somehow stopping my Angular and Nestjs apps from communicating

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs, ngxs

I'm building an app with Angular and NestJS using NGXS for state management.  I got everything set up and served my application and got this error in the console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:333/api/product-index' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

After doing a little research I found [this article](https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/) explaining how to handle CORS in our Angular apps and after checking the files it tells us to modify I saw that the settings were already present.  I was confused about the `server.js` file it told us to update and after looking into what's typically done in a `server.js` file I came to the conclusion that in Angular it must be the `main.ts` file however I don't know if I need to make the modifications to the `main.ts` file in my Nest app or the one in my Angular app.  I'm using a `nrwl nx` monorepo for my apps as well.

This is the `proxy.conf.json` file from my angular app

```
{
    "/cre8or-maker-backend": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3333",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
  }
```

This is the `serve` object of the `architect` object in my `angular.json` file.

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cre8or-maker:build",
            "proxyConfig": "apps/cre8or-maker/proxy.conf.json"
          }
```

As I said before these settings were already present in these files and the only thing that seems new to me is the part about modifying the `server.js` file which I'm assuming is the `main.ts` file in Angular world.  Here's what my `main.ts` files look like

`nest main.ts`

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const globalPrefix = 'api';
  app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
  const port = process.env.port || 3333;
  await app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port + '/' + globalPrefix);
  });
}

bootstrap();
```

`angular main.ts`

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I installed the `cors` npm package already, I just don't know what else I'm suppose to do to get this working, can anyone help?

***UPDATE***
I tried adding `app.enableCors();` to the `main.ts` file in my NestJs app as well as modifying the `create(AppModule)` function to be `create(AppModule, {cors: true})` and neither solve the problem.  I also added the following snippet of code which didn't help either.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
```

As of right now I only have one state defined making an API request to the back end.  Inside my state I have an action which looks like this

```
@Action(GetProductIndexList)
    getProductIndexListData({patchState, dispatch, getState}: StateContext<ProductIndexListModel>){

       return this.dataService.fetchProductIndexList().pipe(tap((result)=>{
            const state = getState();

            patchState({items:[...state.items, ...result]});
        }));
    }
```

I make the api call inside of a service file which I'm calling `dataService` in the state's constructor.  The service file looks like this.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class ProductIndexService{

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    private readonly URL: string = 'localhost:3333/api';

    public fetchProductIndexList():Observable<CattegoryIndexItem[]>{
        const path: string = this.URL + '/product-index';

        return this.httpClient.get(path) as Observable<CattegoryIndexItem[]>;
    }
}
```

In NestJS I can successfully call the data without any errors so I know the controllers are set up properly but if anybody wants to see how I have things set up there let me know and I'll update this question with the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJS enable cors in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949231/nestjs-enable-cors-in-production)

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help.  I tried a couple things from it which I modified my question to show.

Comment: Can you show us where you send your request within the angular app?

Comment: I just updated the question again.

Comment: Try the following change to your URL:
`private readonly URL: string = 'https://localhost:3333/api';`

Comment: in your nest main.ts , add the following lines ` app.enableCors({origin: ['*'],credentials: true or false});`

Comment: ok I made the suggested modifications and the error went away, however I'm getting these errors now
`core.js:6185 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://localhost:3333/api/product-index", ok: false, …}`

and

`GET https://localhost:3333/api/product-index net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: I followed steps mentioned in your question: 
app.enableCORS(); and 
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

and it worked for me to connect my angular app with nestjs api successfully. Thanks

Comment: i add http://   before the localhost:3000 and only with nestjs   app.enableCors(); it works!
i was not need to proxy.conf.json - in the angular ( angular version 13 , nest version 8 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized from the error I was making a request to `localhost:333` rather than `localhost:3333` in the service file sending requests to the backend.  That made the CORS error go away but I still have the other errors which I started a new question to address.

Answer (score 6):

For the following, I just ran into this issue while working on an Angular 13 and Nest.js 8 app in an NX workspace.

For my part, I finally solved this CORS problem by adding the line app.enableCors(); in the main.ts file of the Nest.js application.

```js
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const globalPrefix = 'api';
    app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
    app.enableCors();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    await app.listen(port);
    Logger.log(
        ` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}/${globalPrefix}`
    );
}
```

See the documentation:https://docs.nestjs.com/security/cors