# Nest JS CORS Error 0 Unknown With Android Browsers But Working With PC Broswers

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nestjs

I Use NestJs as a backend server and angular as a frontend
it's okay with me when I use chrome on pc and I can do all my requests
but when I use my android chrome with DevTools I receive this error

message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/users/login: 0 Unknown Error"

here is a snapshot of the error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZQjw.png)

it also send the same error with pc chrome if i didnt open CORS on NestJs

here Is My COSR Config

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log(req);
    next();
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    exposedHeaders: ['x-auth'],
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

by the way when I log the  request on my nest app
I didn't receive any request
I think NestJsrefused it immediately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJS enable cors in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949231/nestjs-enable-cors-in-production)

Answer (score 0):

I found Where is the problem
I was using the localhost as a Backend IP and the application was connecting on my local pc Backend and that was the problem

I solved this by editing the Backend IP to the production IP
and finally, everything works good ,, Thanks All