# Express cors not allowing credentials

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch, passport.js

I have a frontend setup with `react` and a back-end made with `express and mongodb`, I have a component which needs to make a fetch request including the credentials with should be already set. All of the routes work on postman but I'm not able to recreate the functionality with the fetch function.
Express server:

```
...
    server.use(helmet());
    server.use(compression());
    server.use(cors({
      credentials: true,
    }));

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
      server.use(logger("dev"));
    }
    server.use(express.json());
    server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    server.use(cookieParser());

    server.use(
      session({
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
      })
    );

    server.use(auth.initialize);
    server.use(auth.session);
    server.use(auth.setUser);

    //API ROUTES
    server.use("/user", require("./api/routes/user"));
    server.use("/pitch", require("./api/routes/pitch"));
    server.use("/match", require("./api/routes/matchmaking"));
...
```

User routes:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "User logged in correctly",
    redirect: "/"
  });
});

router.get("/checklogin", (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) return next();
  else
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: "User not authenticated"
    });
},
 (req, res, next) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "User logged in correctly",
    redirect: "/"
  });
});
```

Frontend:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/user/checklogin", {
        credentials: 'include'
      });
      const data = await response.json();

      console.log(data);

    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Using this code I get this error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/user/checklogin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

As I said prior everything works on postman but not with the fetch function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'.

When you do this `server.use(cors())`, all of the requests are allowed by default and because of which, the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is set to `'*'`.

So, you might want to specify the `corsOptions` to get around this issue.

```
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000', /** other domains if any */ ]
var corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: function(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

server.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Thank you I did as you said but I get (Unauthorized) even to the user is logged in...

Comment: Hmm, I suppose the LocalStrategy is not set up completely. Have you mounted `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser ` correctly?

Comment: I am also not seeing `passport.init()` and `passport.session()`. Have you followed _all_ the steps from [here](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/)

Comment: I found the solution, it involved the fetch function which wouldn't save the session cookie and that's why it wasn't working but your solution still helped

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Comment: Why use the callback for `origin`? You can directly use an array of allowed domains

Comment: The check might not be sufficient, since for the same origin call, browsers do not send origin. So a `!origin` check is also required. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63684532/4749712

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this 
in express

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

in router

```
router.all('*', cors());
```

while sending response do

```
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:3000');
 res.json(someJson)
```

Comment: There is literally no reason to use both the `cors()` middleware and your own custom, hand-rolled middleware