# Unable to set cookie on a different domain. Express and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have my backend hosted on a server, for example, backend.vercel.app and the frontend on another server, for example, frontend.vercel.app

Whenever a user sends a request to the `/login` route, I am setting the cookie like this:

```js
const setCookie = (req, res, token) => {
  res.cookie('jwt', token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  });
};
```

In the frontend, I am using axios to send a request to the `backend.vercel.app/login` route, with `{withCredentials: true}`

But, the cookie is not being set up, even after a successful login.

The cookies are there in the backend API, but not in the frontend:
[Image of available cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZbXY.png)

What am I missing?

Comment: where are you looking for the cookie? Have you used the browser developer tools to see if a cookie is being sent?

Comment: I did. I am unable to find the cookie anywhere. It's not present in the cookie storage too.

Comment: Do you call `res.end()` at the end?

Comment: I am sending a JSON response at the end with `res.status(200).json({...})`

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
I fixed this issue by manually specifying the `method: 'POST'` in the login request.
And, used this middleware in the backend:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

I also applied the CORS configuration, thanks to the comment made by Kenneth Lew.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you set the cookie on `backend.vercel.app` for example, the cookie you set is only accessible from that same subdomain, and not accessible by other subdomains. In order for the cookie to be shared, you must set the cookie for the parent domain.

Eg:

```
res.cookie('jwt', token, {
   expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
   domain: "vercel.app"
});
```

This should work, however if it doesn't you should check you cors configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. 
This is how CORS is setup:
`app.use(cors({ credentials: true }));`

Comment: I think this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328049/express-cors-not-allowing-credentials
Please tell me if this helps you.

Comment: You might also consider using postman or insomnia to directly test your backend  api and check if the cookie is being set for the subdomain, and if it is, then the issue most likely has something to do with how you are setting the cookie, namely the domain you are setting the cookie for.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried to make the login request in postman. The backend is sending the cookie. Well, I guess, then the frontend is unable to store the cookie?

Comment: I have edited the question a bit. So, if that helps towards finding a solution